# Geometry nodes, match rotation/orientation to the edge

Tags: geometry-nodes, origin, transform-orientation

I made a GN that captures the dimension of an edge. I'd like to **match the rotation** of the **TEXT**(dimension) to the **direction** of the **edge**. also how to **disable origin orientation**.

GN:

[image]

Problem:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *Align Euler to Vector* to calculate Euler rotation to rotate the text by:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank u, Can u explain the second "align Euler..." the one that selected Y?

Comment: @Pooyaheydari you can see in the GIF, that one Euler aligns to the edge, but it has still one dimension of freedom - it is not clear to the "Align Euler" how to rotate the object around the edge. So you align it again, around its (local) $x$ to point up (this way the number is never upside-down)